# Why doesn't my second cron task get run?

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have these two task to be run. The first one gets run every 1 minutes and I want the second one to be run at hour:minute every day every month.

```
*/1 * * * * python /root/vine/hei.py

22 20 * * * python /root/vine/hello.py (to run everyday at 20:22)
```

I waited from 20:20 my local time and see if these two will be run. The second one never gets run when the first one does. Why is it that?

PS: When I change the second task time to be exactly like the first one, it gets run. So the user has necessary permission to run the file.

Comment: How are you confirming it is not done, by outcome of the script or by actual log files that show Cron tasks?

Comment: I am confirming by actually sending an email. Actually these two files have the exact code wrap inside a function each. I got mail from the first one but not the second one.

Comment: I stopped the cron service and restarted it. It's working now..